# How to display dictionary key/value in loop?

Tags: dictionary, julia

I'm assigning each dictionary element into one variable. Is there a way to then get the related key/value out of the variable?

This doesn't work:

```
for letter = Dict("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C")
println("$letter[1] upper case is $letter[2]")
end
```

Output:
"c"=>"C"[1] upper case is "c"=>"C"[2]
"b"=>"B"[1] upper case is "b"=>"B"[2]
"a"=>"A"[1] upper case is "a"=>"A"[2]

I'd like the output to look like this:
"c upper case is C"
"b upper case is B"
"a upper case is A"

I know it can be done using a tuple for the iterated variable but I'd like to use a single variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really don't want to loop by `(key, value)` then all you are missing are the brackets after the `$` in `println`:

```
for letter in Dict("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C")
    println("$(letter[1]) upper case is $(letter[2])")
end
```

Out:

```
c upper case is C
b upper case is B
a upper case is A
```

I would still recommend looping for `(key, value) in my_dict` as that's more readable.

Comment: Your using a tuple, which is explicitly pointed out I don't want to use.

Comment: @4thSpace Okay, I changed the answer. Sorry, I must have skipped over that part.

Comment: "I don't want to use" -  Why not? That is the natural way to do it. Why would you prefer to have the pair in a single object and then access its contents with numerical indices?